# mySQL trigger fails on UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables and one trigger. The trigger fails on the UPDATE on table *sensors*. I have tested the trigger updating another table and that just works fine so I expect this to be a problem with locking on *sensors*. I'm certainly not an expert on mySQL and I did some searching. I have tried to add `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;` before the first SELECT in the trigger but that did not make any difference.

Table *measurements*:

```
CREATE TABLE `measurements` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sensorid` int(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `distance` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `temperature` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26727 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Table *sensors*:

```
CREATE TABLE `sensors` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` char(32) DEFAULT '',
  `zeropoint` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `threshold` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `hysteresis` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('normal','alarm') DEFAULT 'normal',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Trigger *raise* *alarm*:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `raise alarm` BEFORE INSERT ON `measurements`
FOR EACH ROW
begin
    declare zp integer;
    declare st char(32);
    select zeropoint into zp from sensors where id = new.sensorid;
    select status into st from sensors where id = new.sensorid; 
    if new.distance > zp then
        if st = 'normal' then
            update sensors set status = 'alarm' where id = new.sensorid;
        end if;
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: @OP: Add error stack details to your post.

Comment: The failure is that the record is not inserted in table measurements.

Comment: @Ravinder: As said, I'm far from an expert. How would I do that? I have installed mySQL on Mac OS X Yosemite and use Sequel Pro to access mySQL.

Comment: If record is not inserted into measurements, how do you know that? What is interface you are using? If error is thrown, it must be caught! Are you doing that?

Comment: My doubt is that, the insert statement on `measurement` is not executed at all. And hence no trigger fired and hence no update took place.

Comment: @Ravinder I have an Arduino pumping sensor based data into this system and I can clearly see that whenever new.distance > zp, the record is not inserted in measurements. I have no idea how to catch that error. If you do, please give me a hint. I am sure the trigger is executed. As said, when I UPDATE another table than sensors, the UPDATE is executed by the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

There is something in the documentation that you might be interested in: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

> In a BEFORE trigger, the NEW value for an AUTO_INCREMENT column is 0,
>   not the sequence number that is generated automatically when the new
>   row actually is inserted.

It means, that all queries in your trigger are always looking for a record with id=0, since `id` column in measurement table is auto-increment. 
In case there is no record id=0 in sensors table, then zp variable is null, 
and this condition: `if new.distance > zp then` is always false.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not case. I have added and `ELSE` statement in the `if new.distance  zp` clause in which I added the value of zp in another column (removed the UPDATE) and that showed that the value of zp is indeed known at evaluation of the IF/THEN.